# Change the look of GeoServer welcome page

Tags: geoserver, html

Does anyone know how to change the look of GeoServer welcome page? I need to know where to change it.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Change the font size and style

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the CSS files in

```
geoserver/web/wicket/resource/org.geoserver.web.GeoServerBasePage/css
```

Where `geosever` is the folder of the geoserver installation

Comment: There is no web folder inside geoserver installation path